# Http Interceptor Angular 4

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

I'm getting an error in my Typescript file that uses the Angular 4 framework. intelliJ IDE is not able to recognize the any datatype for HttpRequest.

Here is the code:

```
import {Component, Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from "@angular/router";
import {
  HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest,
  HttpResponse, HttpInterceptor, HttpEventType} from "@angular/common/http";
import * as $ from "jquery";

@Injectable()
export class Service {

public getNames() {

   intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
       if (request.responseType == 'json') {
       request = request.clone({ responseType: 'text' });

       return next.handle(req).map(response => {
         if (response instanceof HttpResponse) {
         response = response.clone<any>({ body: JSON.parse(response.body) });
      }

      return response;
    });
  }
}
```

From the following GitHub website: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18396#issuecomment-349403045

I've checked that I'm importing '@angular/common/http' and that my Typescript version is up-to-date (I have version 2.6.2).

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Would be helpful if you indicate what error you got

Comment: I'm getting that the datatype is not recognized or allowed there. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Interceptor should not be in a method. Please read the docs https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-all-requests-or-responses

Comment: This fix works... I had read the docs but missed that detail. Thank you for pointing it out. However, I'm still getting an error in parsing the JSON. Will look into this issue further.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to use interceptors is this:

```
import {
  Injectable,
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {
  Observable
} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() {
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (request.responseType == 'json') {
      request = request.clone({ responseType: 'text' });
    }

    return next.handle(request).map(// your code here)
  }
}
```

find the difference in your code.

Comment: Please explain what you have changed instead to make this a more valuable answer. Answers without explanations are not good answers ;)

Comment: The fact is that the question have not the full interceptor code, and the imports. That's why I just put the correct implementation.