# when to use custom angular HttpInterceptor?

Tags: angular

1.When is it appropriate to use a custom `HttpInterceptor` in Angular?

2.Shouldn't `authentication/authorization` always use `CanActivate` from `@angular/router`?

3.What are some real-world scenarios where I should use a custom `HttpInterceptor` in Angular?

Comment: if you want to send some headers on every request

Comment: i think it's a duplicate [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47661972/http-interceptor-angular-4)

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses

Answer (score 0):

It's primarily for altering every http request you make, for instance you can use it to add bearer token to every requests header in jwt authentication.

Or let's say you want to catch all http errors and show them using some notification system. If you don't use http interceptors you probably have to extend the core http service do to these stuff.